# Rearrange/Reduce Windows Context Menu

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu, rearrange

Windows XP - I have a Context Menu(all kinds) containing many useless commands which i dont use.
I need a utility to help me manage it by removing the unwanted commands.

I currently use [MMM](http://hace-software.com/mmm.shtml) but it gets corrupted after a while(an utility similar to it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a lengthy explanation of how to clean up a messy context menu, using either the registry editor or some freeware NirSoft tools.

[How to Clean Up Your Messy Windows Context Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Context Menu Editor**

> Context Menu Editor can view and
>   delete links to programs in the
>   context menus (the popup menus you see
>   when you right-click) of files,
>   folders and Internet Explorer.Context
>   Menu Editor does not delete the
>   programs, it just removes them from
>   your menus. Menu deletions cannot be
>   undone so please use with care - you
>   may need to reinstall your software if
>   you want them back.

http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Context-Menu-Editor-Download-21482.html

**Context Menu Manager**

> Context menu Manager allows you to
>   quickly and easily Deactivate and
>   Activate context menu elements.
>   Context Menu manager allows you to
>   manage context menus created with a
>   right mouse click in Windows Explorer
>   and on the desktop. In the past, if
>   you installed a program that added
>   entries to your context menu the only
>   way top have them not show up was to
>   uninstall the package.

https://www.techworld.com/download/system-desktop-tools/context-menu-manager-20166024-3330494/

**Mmm Free Edition**

> Every program these days seem to put
>   an extra item or 2 in your
>   context-menu. It is all under the
>   guise of being helpful, but often it
>   is to get the company name (or product
>   name) in the menu. They see it as a
>   place to advertise. And of course it
>   is difficult or impossible to remove
>   these items in an easy way.
>
> The context-menu quickly becomes a
>   mess!
>
> Most of these functions you never use.
>   Some you use sometimes. And some you
>   use all the time. Mmm lets you get rid
>   of the items you never use. Lets you
>   move those items you rarely use out on
>   a submenu. Keeping only the functions
>   you often use in a tidy and small base
>   menu.

https://download.cnet.com/Mmm/3001-2072_4-10396255.html