# Remove "SkyDrive Pro" from context menu?

Tags: windows, context-menu, onedrive, right-click, microsoft-office-2013

I've recently installed Microsoft Office 2013 and noticed a new `SkyDrive Pro` option is added to the context menu when I right click on a file or folder.  I'm not using SharePoint and do not want that extra menu option there.

How do I remove `SkyDrive Pro` from the Context Menu?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows: How to remove items from the right click (context) menu?](http://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the Run Dialog by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
Type in `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a Command Prompt

If you are running 32 bit Office on 32 bit Windows type in

```
regsvr32 /u "%programfiles%\Microsoft Office\Office15\GROOVEEX.DLL"
```

If you are running 32 bit Office on 64 bit Windows type in

```
regsvr32 /u "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office15\GROOVEEX.DLL"
```

If you are running 64 bit Office on 64 bit Windows type in

```
regsvr32 /u "%programfiles%\Microsoft Office\Office15\GROOVEEX.DLL"
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If it was successful you should see this confirmation dialog:

[image]

Note that you must have Administrative rights to do that. For more information see

[Superuser - How to access the Administrator Command Prompt in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8)

[Windows Server Documentation - Start a Command Prompt as an Administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: hi! on 64 bit windows you can also try `regsvr32 /u "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office15\GROOVEEX.DLL"`

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/17646/10259) in another [similar question,](https://superuser.com/q/155271/10259) you can use **[ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html)** to remove Context Menu items.

[image]

Other alternative software for removing context menu items:

- [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) - Its UI makes it easy to disable context menu of a specific file type.
- [MenuMaid](http://www.sdsoftware.org/software/menumaid/) - Its UI makes it easy to disable all context menu from a specific program.